# /home/travis/build.sh: line 41: $pid Killed (exit code 137)

Tags: travis-ci

In the Apache Jackrabbit Oak travis build we have a unit test that
makes the build erroring out

```
Running org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.HeavyWriteIT

/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: 3342 Killed mvn verify -P${PROFILE} ${FIXTURES} ${SUREFIRE_SKIP}

The command "mvn verify -P${PROFILE} ${FIXTURES} ${SUREFIRE_SKIP}" exited with 137.
```

https://travis-ci.org/apache/jackrabbit-oak/jobs/44526993

The test code can be seen at

https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-oak/blob/trunk/oak-core/src/test/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/oak/plugins/segment/HeavyWriteIT.java

What's the actual explanation for the error code? How could we
workaround/solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code 137 usually comes up when a script gets killed due to exhaustion of available system resources, in this case it's very likely memory. The infrastructure this build is running on has some limitations due to the underlying virtualization that can cause these errors.

I'd recommend trying out our new infrastructure, which has more resources available and should give you more stable builds: http://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-12-17-faster-builds-with-container-based-infrastructure/

Comment: thank you @roidrage. Does it happen you have any examples about how to replace the sudo bits? We use it to install MongoDB 2.6.x in the box.

Answer (score 1):

Usually `Killed` message means that you are out of memory. Check your limits by `ulimit -a` or available memory by `free -m`, then try to increase your stack size, e.g. `ulimit -s 82768` or even more.